# Javascript Back Button in Modal - Stop it from closing the modal

Tags: javascript, button, window, modal-dialog, back

How do I get the "back" button seen in my demo to NOT close the modal window?

If this can't be prevented, then at least provide them with a confirmation box alerting them the window is trying to close and ask them if they want to continue.

I'm using a javascript back button link and forward button link to control the user's history inside a modal/lightbox window.

Here's a demo of what is happening... When you begin, the second page will have a link to the modal window, so click that, then click the "back" button in the window as it will take you BACK to the start page. That's the issue I'm having as I don't want this to happen.

http://www.apus.edu/_test/evan/modal/start.htm

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back Button</a> 
<a href="javascript:history.go(1)">Foward Button</a>
```

Comment: You should disable any "back button" when there's nothing in the back.

Comment: That looks to be part of your colorbox.

Comment: If your pages know which page they are (and the certainly appear to), then just don't put a "Back" button on page 1.  That seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @Pointy. Good observation. In my example, I can, but unfortunately, the back and forward button must exist at the template level, not at the page level.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see where they are in the page (ie: the start page having a static back / forward button ) why not just make the back button a javascript:void(0)? If you aren't going to have a defined front location, use server side to store their start place, and once they have reached it, disable the back option.

Comment: unfortunately, server side isn't possible. i'm looking for client side javascript to handle the work. the back/forward button would be at the template level, wouldn't be dynamic, can not be added to the page level.

Comment: Unfortunately javascript has severe restrictions on its actual manipulation of the back / forward options ( you aren't allowed much access to the window.history object ). With the restrictions in place there may not be a way to do what you need. Other than perhaps viewing the pageid you are on ( or equivalent ) and using that to determine if a back button should show

Comment: I was confused at first as well, but @Evan isn't referring to the browser's back button, but the HTML link within his modal popup. I've edited the question to reflect this better.